# MLE: Standard error of function of parameter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, standard-error, fisher-information, hessian

Let's assume I'm fitting some arbitrary model via maximum likelihood. For simplicity let's assume I have only one parameter of interest, $\beta$. Let's choose a probit model to illustrate, with log-likelihood function

$$\mathcal{L}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\log(\Phi(\beta x_{i}))+(1-y_{i})\log(1-\Phi(\beta x_{i}))$$

Now, say I wanted to restrict $\beta$ to be positive and for convenience I decided to perform the following transformation to constrain $\beta$
$$\beta=f(\gamma)=\exp(\gamma)$$

So when I construct my likelihood function I am placing $\exp(\gamma)$ in my function and after minimising the negative log-likelihood I obtain $\hat{\gamma}$. I am familiar with how to generate the standard error for $\gamma$. Given that $\beta=f(\gamma)$, how do I get the standard error for $\beta$.

Comment: In general, you can use something like the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) although I think your whole approach is a little problematic. First, I don't think you should impose the $\beta > 0$ constraint by parameterizing it with $\gamma$. Suppose the true maximum is achieved at some $\beta^* < 0$, and your log likelihood is concave. Then your argmax w.r.t. $\gamma$ will be $-\infty$ and that won't do you any good. I think you need something more involved. See, e.g., https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008669208700

Comment: BTW your $\prod$ should be $\sum$.

Comment: @TimMak Thanks for noting the mistype. The idea of constraining $\beta$ is that I *want* it to be $\geq 0$. I'm not sure I understand your concern, given the invariance principle: if $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then $g(\hat{\theta})$ is the MLE of $g(\theta)$?

Comment: If your MLE $\hat{\beta} > 0$, then it doesn't matter. You don't need to transform and you can obtain results for $SE(\hat{\beta})$. If the unconstrained $\hat{\beta} < 0$, then it means (often) that the constrained $\hat{\beta}=0$. In this case, it is not valid to obtain SE using standard methods (e.g. Fisher's information) since the MLE occurs at the boundary of the parameter space. Transforming $\beta$ to $\gamma$ does not solve this issue.

Comment: BTW an easy solution to the above is to go Bayesian, if you are ok with that.

Comment: @TimMak Thanks again. You've got to the core of my question; the transformation doesn't address the problem of being on the boundary of the parameter space. I had thought that it might have. How would you suggest going about the Bayesian approach, to choose a prior for $\beta$ that has support only above $0$?

Comment: If your data is reasonably large then any weakly informative prior will have little effect on the posterior. A simple prior is for example Uniform(0,c) where $c$ is some suitably large value. If your data is small then you need to choose a prior that actually reflects your belief. Look up the literature on prior elicitation in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in reality $\beta>0$ then for large enough $n$ you will have $\hat\beta>0$ and you can use the delta method

$$\mathrm{var}[\hat\beta] = \left(\frac{d\beta}{d\gamma}\right)^2\mathrm{var}[\hat\gamma]= \beta^2\mathrm{var}[\hat\gamma]$$

In this case the transformation hasn't really gotten you much, but it's valid.

The problem comes when an unconstrained estimator would have $\hat\beta\leq 0$.  In fact, I'm going to write $\hat\beta_u$ for the unconstrained estimator and $\hat\beta_c$ for the constrained estimator $e^{\hat\gamma}$, so the problem comes when an unconstrained estimator would have $\hat\beta_u\leq 0$.

In that case the constrained estimator has $\hat\beta_c=0$ and $\hat\gamma =-\infty$.

If the unconstrained problem has $\hat\beta_u\leq 0$ with non-negligible probability then the constrained estimator has $\hat\gamma=-\infty$ with non-negligible probability and $\hat\beta_c=0$ with non-negligible probability. In that case $\hat\gamma$ **does not have a finite standard error**. While $\hat\beta_c$ *does* have a finite standard error, it does not have an approximately Normal distribution. The standard error can't straightforwardly be used to construct uncertainty intervals, nor can it be estimated simply from the inverse Fisher information.

On the other hand, if $\hat\beta_u\leq 0$ is just an occasional small-sample issue then there isn't much of a problem and you can just use the delta method when $\hat\gamma$ is finite and fudge somehow when $\hat\gamma=-\infty$.